# GWT 2.7.0: Why I have to move my mouse in browser's client area to see actual loaded page?

Tags: gwt, polymer, vaadin, gwt-2.7

I'm developing a webapp prototype using `GWT 2.7.0` and `Vaadin-Polymer-Elements` and I'm wondering about the page loading behaviour. *The browser window remains white, until I move with my mouse cursor over it?!* Even after packaging and deploying the app to an application server, this behaviour persists. Only if I have the chrome developer console open, the page shows up in milliseconds... To reproduce this, simply follow the GWT Polymer tutorial steps.

**Any suggestions how to change this are appreciated.**

Comment: Does this happen in other web browser too? Looks like a chrome issue to me

Comment: This seems to be true. On firefox and edge you can watch how the page builds up, which is ugly too. Maybe I have to show an loading indicator until the page is ready? And I thought, with GWT I don't have to care about browser issues... ;-)